# The most efficient way to calculate an integral in a dataset range

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have an array of 10 rows by 20 columns. Each columns corresponds to a data set that cannot be fitted with any sort of continuous mathematical function (it's a series of numbers derived experimentally). I would like to calculate the integral of each column between row 4 and row 8, then store the obtained result in a new array (20 rows x 1 column).

I have tried using different scipy.integrate modules (e.g. quad, trpz,...).

The problem is that, from what I understand, scipy.integrate must be applied to functions, and I am not sure how to convert each column of my initial array into a function. As an alternative, I thought of calculating the average of each column between row 4 and row 8, then multiply this number by 4 (i.e. 8-4=4, the x-interval) and then store this into my final 20x1 array. The problem is...ehm...that I don't know how to calculate the average over a given range. The question I am asking are:

1. Which method is more efficient/straightforward?
2. Can integrals be calculated over a data set like the one that I have described?
3. How do I calculate the average over a range of rows?

Comment: I may be missing something, but an integral is merely the area under the "curve" so you can just add up the values in each column.

Comment: So you are looking for the sum, not the integral, right?

Comment: The integral is the area under the curve, but that is equals to the mean of your values multiplied by the integration window. So integral (f) between a and b=mean(f)x(b-a)

Comment: But the mean is the total divided by the integration windpw. So integral(f) = `mean(f)` x `(b-a)` = `sum-of-values` / `(b-a)` x `(b-a)` = `sum-of-values`! The area really is the sum of the values...

Comment: I think mean(f)=sum-of-values / number-of-values.

Comment: But no big deal, really...just a matter of using a[4:9].sum vs a[4:9].mean. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Since you know only the data points, the best choice is to use `trapz` (the trapezoidal approximation to the integral, based on the data points you know).

You most likely don't want to convert your data sets to functions, and with `trapz` you don't need to.

So if I understand correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
from numpy import *

# x-coordinates for data points
x = array([0, 0.4, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10])

# some random data: 3 whatever data sets (sharing the same x-coordinates)
y = zeros([len(x), 3])
y[:,0] = 123
y[:,1] = 1 + x
y[:,2] = cos(x/5.)
print y

# compute approximations for integral(dataset, x=0..10) for datasets i=0,1,2
yi = trapz(y, x[:,newaxis], axis=0)
# what happens here: x must be an array of the same shape as y
# newaxis tells numpy to add a new "virtual" axis to x, in effect saying that the
# x-coordinates are the same for each data set

# approximations of the integrals based the datasets
# (here we also know the exact values, so print them too)
print yi[0], 123*10
print yi[1], 10 + 10*10/2.
print yi[2], sin(10./5.)*5.
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the sum of the entries 4 to 8 (including both ends) in each column, use

```
a = numpy.arange(200).reshape(10, 20)
a[4:9].sum(axis=0)
```

(The first line is just to create an example array of the desired shape.)